# ErrorDescription: NoStatus Available

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, oledb, business-intelligence

when Im trying to get the error description by script component,

What Im getting are

```
>     > ErrorCode     ErrorColumn    ErrorDescription
>     > -1071607685   0              No status is available.
```

Same details over and over again,

I followed steps from here [SSIS Nugget: Get error descriptions](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/08/1969.aspx) and
Here is my sample package:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any concerns who are facing the same issue.
Please refer to this [steps of instructions](http://code.commongroove.com/2011/09/16/ssis-use-two-ole-db-destination-adapters-to-catch-insertionconstraint-errors/comment-page-1/).
 This solved my problem